# How can I convert and reduce the size of a ts video?

Tags: conversion

I have season 21 of the Air Crash Investigation TV program. Each episode is around 40-50 minutes and in `ts` format, but it is around 2.4 GB which is unacceptable. I have 2-3 hours movies that are less than 1.5 GB.

So my question is that how can I end up with video files of around 500 MB (or less) and resolution of 720p with any format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use software such as [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) to compress the files.
Compression is a trade off between file size and video quality.
You can choose how much compression to use in the app by [adjusting the quality](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.5.0/workflow/adjust-quality.html).